# ListView getcount row and display in TextView

Tags: android, listview

In my home activity. I have listview with id list and textview with id count.

Here's the code:

```
ListView lv = getListView();

lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
int position, long id) {

int count = 0;
for (int i = 0; i <= list.getLastVisiblePosition(); i++) {
if (list.getChildAt(i) != null) {

count++;
counter.setText(count + "");
}
}
```

I want to display in textview of rows in listview

Comment: @SimplePlan I want to display in textview of how many items are there in listview.

Comment: counter.setText(list.get(i));

Comment: @raj error in list.get

Comment: @raj its a `ListView` not a list

Comment: @Haj Do you have the adapter code??

Comment: counter.setText(myList.getChildAt(i));

Comment: some more code would be helpful

Comment: @Haj use `list.getAdapter().getCount()` will give you the number of row counts

Comment: Thank you for all replies. I will try your codes and I will back here for the output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you want to display how many items is in ListView or visible on screen?

For first option:

If you use ListView, then you have to use some ListAdapter (for example descendant of BaseAdapter or ArrayAdapter) which has method

```
getCount()
```

This returns, how many items is in adapter and also in ListView.

**edit:**

```
TextView countTextView; // here you want to set number of items
ListView lv; // your ListView
BaseAdapter adapter; // your adapter, that is used with ListView

// call this method in some listener
private void showNumberOfItems() {
     int count = adapter.getCount();
     countTextView.setText(String.valueOf(count));
}
```

Comment: Why it's display 10? But I have just 1 row in my listview

Comment: Put whole your code even with adapter and source data.

Answer (score 0):

You can use getLastVisiblePosition() method to count the number of rows,

```
int count=0;
for(int i = 0; i  <= list.getLastVisiblePosition(); i++)
        {
            if(list.getChildAt(i)!= null)
            {

                count++;  // saying that view that counts is the one that is not null, because sometimes you have partially visible items....
            }
        }
```

and then set the Text,

```
counter.setText(count + "");
```

**Edit-**
try something like this,

```
ListView lv = getListView();

lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
int position, long id) {

int count = 0;
for (int i = 0; i <= list.getLastVisiblePosition(); i++) {
if (list.getChildAt(i) != null) {

count++;

}
}
counter.setText(count + "");
```

Comment: Are you sure you are having some rows in your listview ?

Comment: Yes. I have 3 rows in my listview.

Comment: Then you should post some more code. the adapter code ?

Comment: first thing, you should use counter.setText(count+""); method outside the for loop and please edit your question and post the code their.

Comment: Sorry I'm new to Android

Comment: Still the textview is zero

Comment: can you show how you are setting values in the listview.?

Comment: What do you mean? What setting? 


I will post a screenshot.

Comment: No, please post the code. I cant see the screenshot, because images are blocked here. post the enitre class code.

Comment: Check This May This Help You.. http://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-multilevel-listview-tutorial/

Comment: @KaranMavadhiya It's different to what I want. Thank you.

Comment: Ohh, got it. Try using counter.setText(count + ""); method after the setListAdapter(adapter) method.

Comment: This?

counter.setText(count + "");
setListAdapter(adapter);

Comment: No after that, setListAdapter(adapter);  counter.setText(count + "");

Comment: counter.setText(count + ""); after setListAdapter(adapter);

Comment: yes, just like this setListAdapter(adapter); counter.setText(count + "");